# Fubini Theorem to show convergence almost everywhere

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $f_n\geq 0$ and $\sum_n\int f_n<\infty$. I want to show that $$\sum_n f_n$$ converges almost everywhere.

**My attempt:** By Fubini/Tonelli's or alternatively by Dominated Convergence Theorems, $$\sum_n\int f_n=\int\sum_n f_n<\infty\implies \sum_n f_n$$ converges almost everywhere. Is this correct? I feel like I might be missing something.

Comment: you mean $\sum f_n$ converges a.e?

Comment: @peek-a-boo Yes, will fix now.

Comment: Try Beppo Levi. Your argument line is correct.

Comment: @amsmath I am not familiar with Beppo Levi. Is there any other way to show from a finite integral that the integrand must converge a.e.?

Comment: For exchanging the series and integral, Tonelli's theorem works fine if you assume your measure space is $\sigma$-finite. But note that TOnelli's theorem already uses monotone convergence (also known as Beppo Levi's theorem on monotone convergence as amsmath mentions) as part of its proof. So, really this follows immediately from monotone convergence (though I'd be surprised if you haven't learnt monotone convergence yet somehow learnt Fatou's lemma and DCT)

Comment: @peek-a-boo That's interesting.I didn't know that.